# How do I make the simplest Java program with one method?

Tags: java, methods

I need to take an int from the user, plug it into a formula, then return the calculated value.

I feel like I should be able to do this without creating a constructor class, initializing an object, and then calling a method on that class, but I don't know how to. Here is some code that doesn't work, but it is all I have so far. How would I make this streamlined?

```
public class Problem1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    //Let user pick value of n
    System.out.println("Please pick a value of n.");
    int n=input.nextInt();

    Problem1 codeTest = new Problem1();
    codeTest.code(n);
}

public int code(int n) {
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        sum++;
    return sum;
}
```

}

Comment: Use a static method.

Comment: Just move the logic in code() to main().

Comment: Get rid of Problem1 codeTest = new Problem1(). All of your code will start in the main function. The class is just needed to contain the main function (Everything in java has to run in a class). Once you get rid of that just put a System.out.println(code(n)); and you should see some output in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you're inside the `main class` you do not need to instantiate the class itself just use `static` method.

```
public static int code(int n) {
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        sum++;
    return sum;
}
```

then remove

```
 Problem1 codeTest = new Problem1();
    codeTest.code(n);
```

just call the `code()` method

your `main method` would look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    //Let user pick value of n
    System.out.println("Please pick a value of n.");
    int n=input.nextInt();

    code(n) or System.out.println(code(n));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make the method "int code(int n)" static, so that the main method can refer to it without instantiating an object, like so

```
public static int code(int n) {
    //code here
}
```

Then in the main method simply call

```
System.out.println(code(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the method code(int n) in the main class? If you want the codeTest class to use the method, you should first create the codeTest class, and then insert the code() method in that class. If you want to submit the int n to the code() and use only the mainclass, just remove the codeTest.

```
  public class Problem1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

      //Let user pick value of n
      System.out.println("Please pick a value of n.");
      int n=input.nextInt();
      int result = code(n);
  }

  public static int code(int n) {
      int sum=0;
      for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
          sum++;
      return sum;
  }

  }
```

Comment: This won't work.  You can't call a non-static method from a static method without an instance.  The line `int result = code(n);` will have a compile time error.

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method